# Delegate which tells did other sound play in Swift AvAudio?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avaudioengine

I am recording voice using AVAudioEngine for converting speech to text but I need to stop the recording if user phone suddenly start playing a music or ring? Is there an AVAudio delegate that tells me when any other music is playing?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your AVAudioSession's category is `playback` (the default one), then you can subscribe to and receive notifications of such interruptions:

```swift
func setupNotifications() {
    let nc = NotificationCenter.default
    nc.addObserver(self,
                   selector: #selector(handleInterruption),
                   name: AVAudioSession.interruptionNotification,
                   object: AVAudioSession.sharedInstance)
}
@objc func handleInterruption(notification: Notification) {
    guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
        let typeValue = userInfo[AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] as? UInt,
        let type = AVAudioSession.InterruptionType(rawValue: typeValue) else {
            return
    }

    // Switch over the interruption type.
    switch type {

    case .began:
        // An interruption began. Update the UI as necessary.

    case .ended:
       // An interruption ended. Resume playback, if appropriate.

        guard let optionsValue = userInfo[AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionKey] as? UInt else { return }
        let options = AVAudioSession.InterruptionOptions(rawValue: optionsValue)
        if options.contains(.shouldResume) {
            // An interruption ended. Resume playback.
        } else {
            // An interruption ended. Don't resume playback.
        }

    default: ()
    }
}
```

From [the relevant documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/responding_to_audio_session_interruptions).